# Force set_shape on Tensorflow Tensor

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I would like to change the shape of a tensorflow tensor. `set_shape` does not work in this case because I am trying to re-define previously defined dimensions:

```
ValueError: Shapes (?, 144, 192, 1) and (?, 212, 156, 1) are not compatible
```

this seems to work, but required accessing a protected field:

```
t._shape = tf.TensorShape([tf.Dimension(x) for x in new_shape])
```

Is there a better way to do this? I know what I am doing here and *would* like to forcibly change the shape of the tensor.

Comment: There's deliberately no API for relaxing the inferred shape of a tensor once it has been computed, because it can lead to invalid graphs. If the inferred shape is wrong, that would be a bug in the shape inference (and we'll certainly fix it); if you want to permit feeding values of different shapes then you can use `tf.placeholder_with_default(x)` to create a tensor that has a more permissive shape than the default value `x`.